# FastAPI pagination with resource coming from RESTful APIs

Tags: python, pagination, fastapi

I'm trying to implement an endpoint in my fastAPI application where I 'm trying to gather some resources (job items) from various RESTful resources and after normalisation return them to the caller.

Problem is that pagination doesn't seem to work as I expected as requesting the 2nd page of my results makes all subsequent RESTful APIs to get called again, hence the response time takes just as much the first page required.

My idea was that, per [documentation](https://uriyyo-fastapi-pagination.netlify.app/), the pagination adds all results in memory so that next page call the data are already available. Am I missing something here?

```
@router.get("/job_search",
            response_model=Page[Job],
            summary="Get jobs from various sites based on keyword", tags=["Job search"])
@has_permissions(Permissions.PUBLIC_PERMISSION_LEVEL)
def search_jobs(keyword: str = Query(), user: User = Depends(user_db_crud.get_current_user)):
    """
    Returns jobs found in various sites based on keyword.
    """
    try:
        jobs = search_jobs(preprocess_string(keyword))
        return paginate(jobs)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=500, detail=f"An unexpected error occurred. Report this message to support: {e}")

@timing_decorator
def search_jobs:
    url = "some url here"
    response = requests.get(url)
    .
    .
    process here
    .
    .
    return jobs
```

```
INFO:     Started server process [19894]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:9999 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Function search_jobs took 48.73508310317993 seconds to run.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55747 - "GET /v1/job_search?keyword=%CE%BF%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%82&page=1&size=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Function search_jobs took 52.42994689941406 seconds to run.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:55752 - "GET /v1/job_search?keyword=%CE%BF%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%82&page=2&size=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: which library you are using for pagination and what is return type of search_jobs method?

Comment: I'm using fastapi_pagination, but I sorted that out already. It appears that the library doesn't have a feature of cache itself so I just used a cache decorator for my function. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the library [doesn't have a feature of cache](https://github.com/uriyyo/fastapi-pagination/issues/596) itself so I just used a cache decorator for my function. Thanks anyway!

```
    from functools import cache
    
    @cache
    def search_jobs(...):
        pass
```